# Azure Automation: Runbook, RunAs Account: How to allow access to AAD (e.g. for Get-AzADUser)?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, azure-automation, azure-runbook

Good afternoon

I have selected stackoverflow for this question because probably mainly programmers are confronted with this question:

#### This is the issue:

If we call `Get-AzADUser` to get all AAD Users in the Azure Automation Runbook, then we get: `Error 'Insufficient privileges'`

#### We do it like this:

1. We have an Automation Account with an "Azure Run As Account"
2. In the PowerShell Runbook we call:

```
    # Connect to AAD
    $Conn = Get-AutomationConnection -Name AzureRunAsConnection
    $account = Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal `
               -TenantId $Conn.TenantID  `
               -ApplicationId $Conn.ApplicationID  `
               -CertificateThumbprint $Conn.CertificateThumbprint
    # Get All AAD Users
    $AllADUsers = Get-AzADUser
```

3. If we start the Runbook, we get the Error:

```
> Get-AzADUser : Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
> FullyQualifiedErrorId :
> Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ActiveDirectory.GetAzureADUserCommand
```

#### This is the permissions configuration:

1. The `Automation Account` has set `Run as accounts` » `Azure Run As Account` (and not an Azure Classic Run As Account)
2. In fact, `Azure Run As Account` is misleading, it is a Registered App and can be found in Azure `App registrations`
3. The Registered App has these settings:

» A custom role with *all* permissions.

» API Permissions:

```
Microsoft Graph (6)
Delegated    Directory.AccessAsUser.All
Delegated    Directory.ReadWrite.All
Delegated    User.ReadWrite.All
Application  Directory.ReadWrite.All
Application  User.Export.All
Application  User.ReadWrite.All
```

» All API Permissions are Granted for our Tenant

Unfortunately, we still get the Error 'Insufficient privileges'

Thanks a lot for any help!

Kind regards,
Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to some test, you need to add the permissions of Azure AD but not Micorsoft Graph. It seems the `Get-AzADUser` command use Azure AD graph in the backend but not microsoft graph. So we need to do the operations as below:
[image]

[image]

After that we can use the command Get-AzADUser successfully(**if you test the command in powershell, when you add the Azure AD permission, please close the powershell and reopen it and re-connect to avoid the impact of cache**)

I test it in my side, it shows same error with yours' and it can get the users successful after adding this permission. Hope it helps~

[image]