# Azure Automation Account access- AD & WVD Hostpool (add/remove) Operations

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-automation, wvd

I have a automation account with run as account through which i'm running a powershell runbook. It usually does add/remove a member to a AD group in azure and add/remove user to a WVD hostpool. My issue is run as account doesn't have sufficient permission to do the operations.

What level of access (on my account as well as run as account) required to do these activities?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*To perform operations like adding/removing a user from Azure Ad group via PowerShell runbook, your Automation account should have **owner/contributor** role assigned.*

> The **Owner role** allows access to all resources and actions within an Automation account including providing access to other users, groups, and applications to manage the Automation account.

> The **Contributor role** allows you to manage everything except modifying other user’s access permissions to an Automation account.

Based on your requirement you can **assign roles** as provided in the below **MsDoc**:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-role-based-access-control#roles-in-automation-accounts

- To assign roles to your Azure Automation Account via Azure Portal,

***Go to Azure Portal -> Automation Accounts -> Your Account -> Access Control (IAM) -> Add Role***

[image]

- Make sure to give **Directory Readers role** like below:

***Go to Azure portal -> Azure AD -> Roles and Administrator ->Directory Readers role -> Assign this role to the runbook account name***

[image]

For more in detail, please **refer** below links:

[Trying to connect with Azure AD from Automation runbook account but getting Code: Authorization_RequestDenied - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62588052/trying-to-connect-with-azure-ad-from-automation-runbook-account-but-getting-code)

https://www.buchatech.com/2018/07/the-argument-is-null-or-empty-error-in-azure-automation-runbook/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/delete-host-pool?tabs=azure-portal

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and kindly suggest permissions required for WVD hostpool through azure automation account as i asked above.

Comment: To know the required permissions of WVD hostpool, please check this link      [WVD permissions](https://blog.itprocloud.de/Windows-Virtual-Desktop-Admin/#wvd-permissions-classic--fall-version)